# Why does the Standard deviation formula when using coded data not account for the addition or subtraction of coded part

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, standard-deviation, dataset, teaching

When we code data from x to x-b the standard deviation formula is:
Sd(x)=sd(x-b)= (sum of(x-b)^2)/n - (sum of (x-b)/n)^2

Why do they not use (sum of (x-b)/n +b )^2 for the second part since this is supposed to be the mean squared. Mean of coded data accounts for the -b by adding b so why do we not do this for sd?

Comment: $V(aX\pm b)  = a^2V(X)$ so $SD(aX \pm b) =|a|SD(X).$ // If the SD of the ages of the students in a class is $5,$ and everybody shows up for a class reunion in ten years, then everybody will be ten yours older, but the SD of their ages will still be $5.$